# How do you find out when new data is loaded via ajax in a firefox addon?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am creating an addon for firefox with the new addon builder.  I would like to have an event fired when data is loaded with an XMLHttp request so I can run a script to add in some extra features.  Similar to a page load except the site uses ajax.  This is my first addon and I'm not sure how to go about doing this.  I looked around and there was this method

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.getResponseHeader=function(){
    runCheck();
};
```

But when I added it in the console tells me that there is no XMLHttpRequest.prototype.  I had tested it by loading it in firebug and it worked, but when I try to use in the content script it doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

There's a little known event called DOMSubtreeModified, which fires when the DOM Subtree is Modified (big surprise there).  I read some place that it is supposed to be deprecated, but I can't remember where.  Check the [DOM event reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM_Events).